# error while generating android signed app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, compiler-errors

i am getting this error while generating android signed app

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

this is my files 
[image: image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: try compiling it with jdk 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error once. For me increasing the Java maximum heap size solved the error. Try adding

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    ...
}
```

to your build.gradle file.

Another reason for this error can be that your app is to big and you need to enable multidex support. Please see [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)